# Repeat PdfPTable header in all the continuation pages using iText

Tags: java, itext

How can I repeat the headings of a `PdfPTable` in all the pages if the length of the table exceeds one page?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Look at `setHeaderRows(int headerRows)` of `PdfPTable`. Rows defined there as a header should persist on new pages.

```
table.setHeaderRows(1)
```

for the first row as a header.

See the [API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setHeaderRows%28int%29).

Comment: My requirement is not to repeat heading for PdfPTable on all pages. Even if I comment this line, it still repeats. Any suggestions?

Comment: I did set to 0 but to no avail. Also cudn't find anything worthwhile in linked doc. Hopeless right now..

Comment: @sunny_dev It's been quite a while, but did you ever find a solution to your problem?