# itextsharp multipage table with header and footer text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf generator that has some text at the top and the bottom of a page with a table in the middle. The table is set to a fit length of rows. Everything works except that the PdfPTable table retains the values of the previously added rows so when I go to output the pdf it retains the last table. Is there a way to add a new table with the same variable or clear the current variable?

```
            doc.Open();

            Paragraph header = new Paragraph("header");
            header.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("footer");
            footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SetWidths(widths);
            table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;

            foreach (T t in results)
            {
                if (counter % 50 == 0)
                {
                    if (counter != 0)
                    {
                        doc.Add(table);
                        doc.Add(footer);
                        doc.NewPage();
                    }
                    doc.Add(header);
                    table.AddCell("Name"); //Table Header
                    table.AddCell("Address"); //Table Header
                    table.AddCell("Phone"); //Table Header

                }
                    table.AddCell("First Last"); //individual cell from t.name
                    table.AddCell("Address"); //individual cell from t.address
                    table.AddCell("Phone"); //individual cell from t.phone
            }
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Add(footer);
            doc.Close();
```

Comment: Your code is very strange. Where did you get your inspiration? Did you read about page events to add headers and footers? Did you read about table headers and table footers? Also: why are you surprised that the table retains its rows if you keep using the same table instance?

Comment: You aren't incrementing the `counter` anywhere. I want to correct your code, but I have no idea what your code is supposed to do. Not increasing the counter doesn't make sense. What is that `counter` variable for?

Comment: It's as if you have read something about using a `PdfPTable` as a `LargeElement`, but failed to understand what that was about.

Comment: If you don't reply to my comments, I am going to close your question by referring to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34505550/1622493

Comment: Sorry I am new to using stack overflow to answer questions, I usually find what I am looking for. I striped most of the code trying to just show the particular problem but I guess I didn't share enough. There is a counter for the counter ++ within the foreach loop. I did read about header and footer events but they were not implementing in the way I needed to use them.  I will try to be more through with my question  next time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by just adding: `table = new PdfPTable(5);` within the if statement `if (counter != 0)`

Comment: Seems hard to believe that this solves the problem, but if you say so...